# VB.NET - Checking FTP directory exists always returns true

Tags: vb.net, ftp

Can anybody tell me why the function below always returns true, even if the FTP directory in question does not exist?

The value of directoryURL which I pass in is of the form:

`ftp://ip_address/directory/subdirectory/`

and has a trailing forward slash.

```
Public Function DoesDirectoryExist(directoryUrl As String) As Boolean
  ' Check that the target URL is properly formatted
  If Not directoryUrl.StartsWith("ftp://") Then directoryUrl = "ftp://" & directoryUrl

  ' Create a web request
  Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(directoryUrl), FtpWebRequest)
  request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(_userName, _password)
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory

  ' Try and list the contents of the directory
  Try
    Using response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
      ' We have been succesful so the directory exists
      Return True
    End Using
  Catch ex As WebException
    Dim response As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ex.Response, FtpWebResponse)
    If response.StatusCode = FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable Then
      Return False
    Else
      Throw New ApplicationException("Unable to determine if FTP directory exists.")
    End If
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Does the status code (`response.StatusCode`) differ if the directory exists or not?

Comment: The status code is always 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. This works for me (I don't cast the request but I guess that shouldn't matter). This is the code I usually rely on:

```
Dim response As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Using (response)
    found = True
End Using
```

The alternative you have is reading the list of directories:

```
Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("tempfile", False)
        sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd())
    End Using
End Using
```

In the worst scenario, it should help you to tackle the problem (e.g., it always founds a directory called "ghost", which you might use to trigger the not-found).

Comment: I might have to give the alternative a go. Any good suggestions for parsing the response?

Comment: The response body looks like this: "<PRE>200 Type set to I
200 Port command successful
550 File not found
</PRE>" - so there is a 550 being returned in the response but the code is not set correctly.

Comment: I just checked the response body for a 550 code in the end. Bit crude bit it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Buchanan Happy to be of help. I didn't reply you before because I didn't get any of your messages (stackoverflow is very reliable, I love it; but I have observed that some times you don't get any warning for income messages, mainly for comments when you don't include the @). Anyway... happy you found the solution and happy to know about this weird issue I will take note of.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
Public Function DirectoryExists(directory As String) As Boolean
Dim directoryExists__1 As Boolean

Dim request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(directory), FtpWebRequest)
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")

Try
    Using request.GetResponse()
        directoryExists__1 = True
    End Using
Catch generatedExceptionName As WebException
    directoryExists__1 = False
End Try

Return directoryExists__1
End Function
```

**Method 2**

```
  If Not DirectoryExists("ftp://" + FTPSettings.IP + "/" + lo_ScreenShotPath) Then
        reqFTP = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://" + FTPSettings.IP + "/" + lo_ScreenShotPath)), FtpWebRequest)
End If
```

i  hope may i help this...